# Can you use Mongo's populate function with Mongoid

Tags: mongoid

I have a list of Documents which each have a reference to another document in them. I want to sort the parent list based on a property in the referenced document. This seems like an obvious place to use Mongo's populate function but I can't seem to find anything regarding it.

Comment: [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) is part of Mongoose which is another ODM like Mongoid. This is not core functionality of MongoDB. Just a way to "eager load" referenced data. MongoDB native functionality is "embedding"

Comment: Mongoid supports [relations](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/relations.html), which are similar to the `populate()` feature in Mongoose and other ODMs. The MongoDB server (as at 2.6) does not have any support for populating relationships, so sorting a parent document based on a property in a referenced document will involve client-side application joins & sorting.